# I'e just started learning Django and i got stuck while creating a virtrualenv for some project,What does this mean?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Evalyns-iMac:trydjango2 Evalyn$ virtualenv -p python3
usage: virtualenv [--version] [--with-traceback] [-v | -q] [--read-only-app-data] [--app-data APP_DATA] [--reset-app-data] [--upgrade-embed-wheels] [--discovery {builtin}] [-p py] [--try-first-with py_exe]
[--creator {builtin,cpython3-posix,venv}] [--seeder {app-data,pip}] [--no-seed] [--activators comma_sep_list] [--clear] [--no-vcs-ignore] [--system-site-packages] [--symlinks | --copies] [--no-download | --download]
[--extra-search-dir d [d ...]] [--pip version] [--setuptools version] [--wheel version] [--no-pip] [--no-setuptools] [--no-wheel] [--no-periodic-update] [--symlink-app-data] [--prompt prompt] [-h]
dest
virtualenv: error: the following arguments are required: dest
SystemExit: 2

Comment: please read the faq to ask better question. add some explanation about the problem you're facing

Answer (score 0):

> `virtualenv: error: the following arguments are required: dest SystemExit: 2`

You need to provide a destination folder for virutalenv. You haven't provided any, hence you're getting this error.

Example of correct command:

```
virtualenv -p python3 venv
```

This will create a virtualenv with packages and dependencies in `venv` folder.